# Querying from postgresql server from Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm executing this query

```
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")) 
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
isbn = 03759
a = db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE idnumber LIKE '%:temp%'", {"temp":isbn}).fetchall()
```

A picture of the books table is referenced:
[books database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEpZO.png)

I want to query the rows which have 03759 in their idnumber but python does not allow to add leading zeroes. I tried converting it to string and ran the query but it gave me an error since there was an extra pair of quotes like this:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE idnumber LIKE '%'03759'%'
```

This is how it got converted by sqlalchemy. Is there any workaround to this so that I can query only those which have 03759 in their idnumber?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Maybe use f-string to first generate the query string and then use it in the execute command

```
isbn = '03759'
q = f"SELECT * FROM books WHERE idnumber LIKE '%{isbn}%'"
a = db.execute(q).fetchall()
```

EDIT:

I think Ilja Everilä is correct, the above code is susceptible to query injection, if the the variable `isbn` comes from a user input. To fix this problem use this, as given in the Ilja Everilä answer:

```
isbn = '03759'
q = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE idnumber LIKE :isbn"
q_params = { "isbn": f"%{isbn}%" }
a = db.execute(text(q), q_params).fetchall()
```

Comment: Thanks!!! That worked.

Comment: What the above comic is conveying is that using string formatting to pass values to SQL queries leads to injection, not to mention it is error prone. It is like using `eval()`.